# Prove an inequality $\prod_{j=1}^q (x_j + 1) \leq 2^p$ for $\sum_{j=1}^qx_j = p$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $x_j$, $1 \leq j \leq q \leq p$, be some non-negative integers such that $\sum_{j=1}^q x_j = p$. How to determine whether the following inequality is true
\begin{align*}
(x_1 + 1) (x_2 + 1) \cdots (x_q + 1) \leq 2^p.
\end{align*}
If it is true, how to prove the inequality?

Comment: I guess in the first line you want $1 \leq j \leq q \leq p$ instead of $1 \leq j \leq p \leq q$.

Comment: @Vincent  There seems no actual difference between them.

Comment: @ Vincent Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall Bernoulli's inequality
$$(1+x)^\alpha\ge1+\alpha x,~\text{ for $\alpha\ge 1$ and $x>0$}$$
As a corollary(taking $x=1$), 
$$(1+\alpha)^{1/\alpha}\le2,~\text{ for $\alpha\ge 1$}$$
Now AM-GM implies
\begin{align}\prod_{j=1}^q(x_j+1)&\le\left(1+\frac p q\right)^q\\
&=\left(\left(1+\frac p q\right)^{q/p}\right)^p\\
&\le 2^p\quad(\text{here we used Bernoulli's inequality})
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It is true.

First prove the $q = 1$-case, i.e. prove that for all non-negative integers $x$ we have $x + 1 < 2^x$. Second show how the general case follows from repeated application of this special case.